# Issues compiling React Native for iOS 13 on xcode 11.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

There are no Swift libraries being included in the archive built for iOS 13, Xcode 11.1, RN 0.59

When targeting older versions we are able to archive correctly but we would like to archive specifically for "iOS 13". We also tried copying the old libraries over but that seems to cause issues in the app.

We expected for the Swift folders in the archive to automatically compile but instead we either have to target an old version or manually move them over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try targeting iOS 12.2 and then iOS 12.1. If it still doesn’t include them for 12.2 but does include them for 12.1 then it’s not a problem. What’s happening is that iOS 12.2 and above already include the Swift libraries, so the app no longer needs to include them.